# Uncaught Ext.AbstractManager.register(): Registering duplicate id

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

In the application below, I am trying to add `id`'s to the generated items dynamically. My code works fine but when I add the below two commented lines in it. It throws error

> Uncaught Ext.AbstractManager.register(): Registering duplicate id "73" with this manager

---

When I tried to find out the source of error, I found that the code is working fine till the execution of `81` id's (`console.log(_idGen)`). From this, it is clear that the error is related to out of range exception. (9*9 = 81) and also ***only in Fiddle***, when I add HTML text to the child panels, I came to know that they are between `73 to 81`??(instead of `1 to 81`) which is confusing me, how?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v7hZH/1/)**

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
  var _idGen = 1;
  var childItems = [], items = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    childItems.length = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
       childItems.push({
           xtype: 'panel',
 /****************************/
           id: _idGen,
           html: _idGen + "",
 /****************************/
           width: 50,
           height: 50,
           style: {borderWidth: '1px'}
       });
       console.log(_idGen);
/*****************************/
       _idGen++;
/*****************************/
    }
    items.push({
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 3
        },

        items: childItems
    });
  }
  Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
     layout: {
        type: 'table',
        // The total column count must be specified here
        columns: 3
     },
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),    
     style: {width: '455px',marginLeft: 'auto',marginRight: 'auto', marginTop: '30px'},
     items: items
  });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't create Id's by your won if not strictly required!

It will always be a source of errors so why bother yourself with that when the framework already take care.

Use custom identifier properties or better, the one that is already supported by the framework `itemId`. This property need only to be unique within each component level. You can also use the `getComponent('your-item-id')` method to receive a component that is nested into the calling one.

I've modified your example to use `itemId's` and provided you demo query at the bottom

See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7hZH/2/)**

```
var _idGen = 1,
      _outerIdGen = 1;
  var childItems = [], items = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  // You will keep the same array with and just alter all instances each time. 
  // This is what causes all your problems and the duplicates!      
  // childItems.length = 0; 
  // But you need a new array each time
    childItems = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
       childItems.push({
           xtype: 'panel',
           itemId: 'inner-'+_idGen++,
           html: _idGen + "",
           width: 50,
           height: 50,
           style: {margin: '1px',borderColor: 'white',backgroundColor:'cornflowerblue'}
       });
    }
    items.push({
        xtype: 'panel',
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 3
        },
        itemId: 'outer-'+_outerIdGen++,
        items: childItems
    });
  }
  Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
     layout: {
        type: 'table',
        // The total column count must be specified here
        columns: 3
     },
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),    
     style: {width: '455px',marginLeft: 'auto',marginRight: 'auto', marginTop: '30px'},
     items: items
  });
  console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('container > panel[itemId=outer-1] > panel[itemId=inner-73]')[0]);
```

Comment: Can you please come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23760/sencha.. If you have time :) (others are also welcome)

Comment: @Mr_Green I've edited the code inline with comments. In short: you kept the same array where you needed 9 unique arrays

Comment: yes thankyou :).. the Id's are being generated with a suffix of `body`

Comment: @Mr_Green This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7hZH/5/) use the `id` props again. That will enable you to use Ext.getCmp('id')

Comment: Please have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/14706218/1577396 (sorry, as I am beginner I am getting more doubts)